Is it okay to delete Developer ID Application certificate from keychain?
I download 'Developer ID Application' in mistake as I renew certificates.
But apple doesn't offer to way of deleting it from Xcode or console.

As I searched, once it is generated, whenever I run this project from other computer, I need to export it and move it to new computer..
Can I delete it from keychain here?
I'm afraid to touch it carelessly and not able to use app.


Developer ID Application certificates are used to sign macOS applications for distribution outside of the Mac App Store. This kind of certificate is not required for iOS development/distribution and its existence will not impact your iOS development processes.
There is no option to delete/revoke Developer ID Application certificates. As long as you keep the private key secure, there is no impact from having such a certificate exist.
If you really want to remove it, you can submit a request to Apple developer support.
If you delete it from your Keychain and don't have a backup of the private key, then the keys for that certificate will be lost forever and the certificate will be unusable.  This will ensure that your keys can never leak and no-one can ever issue a MacOS app as "you" with that certificate, but again it will have no impact on your iOS development process and the certificate will still appear in your developer account.

Thanks for your help. I found that it may be deleted from keychain (I update it on my post). Is it okay to delete it from there manually?
